# 0 appears when outputting a shuffled array

Tags: c

I've made a shuffling type program that obtains from `cases[];` and arranges them in a random order.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void deal(void);

int cases[22] =      {1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,15,20,25,35,50,65,85,100,105,135,165,200,250};

int main()
{

   srand(time(NULL));

  int a = 0;

  deal();

  for(a = 0 ; a < 22 ; a++)
  printf("%d \n", cases[a]);

 return 0;
}

void deal(void){
 int loop;
 int temp;
 int x;
 int y;

 for(loop = 0; loop < 50; loop++){

    x = rand() % 22;
    y = rand() % 22;

    temp = cases[x];
    cases[x] = cases[y];
    cases[y] = temp;
 }
}
```

However when I run the code it comes with a randomly placed `0`. Where is it from and why is it there?

Example output:

```
6
15
0 //I don't want that
20
5
50
10
3
165
65
135
105
8
1
200
25
100
85
2
250
4
```

Comment: An off by one error ?

Comment: You better change the title

Comment: Use `sizeof(cases)/sizeof(cases[0])` to calculate dim of your array. Avoid using magic numbers...

Comment: ↑ Or `#define` the magic number.

Comment: Or `enum { NAME = magic_num };`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare your array as:

```
int cases[22] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,15,20,25,35,50,65,85,100,105,135,165,200,250};
```

Without you know it, there is actually only 21 elements in that array. Thus, in C standard compilers, the non-initialized value would be set as zero. To correct it, add one more element to the array.

```
int cases[22] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,15,20,25,35,50,65,85,100,105,135,165,200,250, 500}; // add 500
```

And things will be okay.

Anyway, for this kind of initialization, I recommend you to put the elements in multiple lines (say, every 10 elements):

```
int cases[22] = {1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  8,  10,  15, 20,
                 25, 35, 50, 65, 85, 100,105,135,165,200,
                 250, 500}; // add 500
```

And put in nice format to avoid such error.

Comment: but I want to access prizes[0] too. Since it should only be mixing  the array.

Comment: "_in some C compiler_" -- All standard compliant compilers will set it to zero.

Comment: @CoolGuy not really... I have a uVision IDE whose compiler does not put the initial value as zero... And it gave me trouble in the past..

Comment: @Ian Did you test this? Maybe you did `int n;` in which case accessing `n` is UB. Try something like `int array[20] = {1, 2};` and print all the array element.

Comment: @CoolGuy yes, I did... that's why what I did for my project that time, I always have to do `memset(arr, 0, size)` to ensure that my arrays are all initialized as zero

Comment: Hmm. What compiler does that IDE use?

Comment: @Ian Are you sure about your linker script, at that time?

Comment: @LPs that project was a couple of years back and I no longer have that IDE since now I am not working with microcontroller anymore. And unfortunately I did not check the linker script at that time too. If you have been working with uC before, you may experience similar problem with mine. Anyway, if you want to know about the IDE, check this out: http://www2.keil.com/mdk5/uvision/ it is specifically made for microcontrollers programming in C

Comment: @CoolGuy but you could be right... perhaps what is used by the IDE is a non-standard compiler. Why not I leave that possibility open? It is possible for the IDE to have the compiler having such behavior for some optimizations reason, specific/non-specific to the micro-controllers.

Answer (score 6):

You declared `int cases[22]` but initialized only 21 integers into that array and therefore, the last element will be 0 when not initialized. Try to add another integer at the end of the array

Comment: Oh, so you don't need an extra number or the null zero

Comment: @Bonediggerninja That is required only in case of character arrays.

Answer (score 4):

It's an off by one error: Ferico Samuel's answer is correct

This is a complement:

Instead of hard coding `22` as the number of cases you should write your program like this:

```
// no explicit declaration of the size here. The compiler automatically
// puts the correct size depending on the number of elements that follow.
int cases[] =      {1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,15,20,25,35,50,65,85,100,105,135,165,200,250};
...
for(a = 0 ; a < sizeof(cases) / sizeof(cases[0]); a++)
...
```

`sizeof(cases)` is the size of your `cases` array in bytes
`sizeof(cases[0])` is the size of one element of the `cases`array
thus `sizeof(cases) / sizeof(cases[0])`is the number of elements of the array.

This way you can add more elements to the `cases` array without the need to change the array size elsewhere in your program.

Comment: I'd recommend avoiding this unless you are really familiar with the difference between arrays and pointers. The `sizeof` trick is only possible because 1. you are working with an explicit array type, and 2. the `cases` variable is not passed to a function, at which point it would have decayed to a pointer and the `sizeof` result would not be what is expected.

Answer (score 3):

You have the wrong number of elements in the array. C is a bit stupid, because it is designed so that a compiler can only detect if there is too many elements in an array, but never if there is too few.

To ensure the exact amount of elements, you can declare arrays like this:

```
#define ARRAY_ITEMS(arr) (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr))
#define CASES_ITEMS 22

int cases[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,15,20,25,35,50,65,85,100,105,135,165,200,250};

_Static_assert(ARRAY_ITEMS(cases) == CASES_ITEMS, "Wrong array size: cases");
```